# Why does an SMPS use LCR on INPUT?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, emc, emi-filtering, lcr

I have this 5 V output SMPS I bought a while ago. I was wondering why there are LCRs connected to the input of my SMPS. I don't understand why it's there.

BTW, I'm an electrical engineering student, and I know the basics of LCR, but I am not sure what it's doing here.

[image]

Comment: LCR? Where? What's that?

Comment: Do you mean the resistor near the yellow thing, the yellow thing and the transformer-like thing ?

Comment: @winny resistor,capacitor,inductor in parellel

Comment: @LongPham yes, i will reupload

Comment: It's a filter which prevents (reduces) the SMPS switching noise from going back into the mains.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image: Generic image]

The yellow thing is an X-capacitor, C11 in the above schematic. The resistor is to discharge said X-capacitor within legal requirements (usually 34 V within 1 second after unplugging), R14 in the schematic. L is an common mode choke, X3 in the schematic. They all form the EMI supression from the power supply to the mains, again within legal requirements.

Please see this old question for more information: *[X capacitor selection for SMPS power supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/270857/x-capacitor-selection-for-smps-power-supply)*

Comment: And block spikes from mains too.

Comment: I was trying to figure this for few months and decided to ask here today. I also searched in google, but didn't know that I will be able to find results until I use X-Capacitor word. Thanks for your explanation

Comment: @Aimkiller You are welcome!

Answer (score 11):

This is a filter that sits between the mains power line and the SMPS. Its goal is to suppress electromagnetic interference (EMI) and (to some extent) protect the circuit from spikes on the line. The basic structure of such a filter looks like this:

[image: Line filter]

These filters use specially-rated capacitors to handle the high AC voltage. The capacitors used between the hot and neutral lines (inputs 1 and 2, outputs 3 and 4) are called "X-class capacitors", or "X capacitors" for short. The capacitors used between a hot or neutral line and ground are called Y-class capacitors. The X and Y stuff is just a safety rating; it means the capacitors can survive the line conditions.

Also in the filter is a pair of coupled inductors which form a common-mode filter. This allows the differential line voltage through, but blocks any voltage spikes that are on both lines at once.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation. both answers explained it well for me.

Comment: The safety rating doesn't just mean the caps will survive the line conditions.  It also means that if the cap is subjected to conditions it cannot survive, it will fail open rather than shorted.