# How do I choose a value for an X-capacitor?

Tags: emi-filtering

I am working on designing an EMI input filter, and I was wondering how I should go about choosing a value (capacitance) for the X-capacitor. I found a post (linked below) which talked about calculating the power factor, and then choosing a cap that gave you a decent power factor (without being too greedy.)

Is this the only way to do it, or are there any other design guidelines I should be aware of?

I know that eventually we would test our board to make sure it is in compliance, but I am more so wondering about guidelines for the initial component selection.

[X capacitor selection for SMPS power supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/270857/x-capacitor-selection-for-smps-power-supply)

Comment: RGB Engineer, are you done with this question now or do you still need some help?

Comment: Hello, I am still formulating my next question in my head.

Answer (score 2):

> *I found a post (linked below) which talked about calculating the power
> factor, and then choosing a cap that gave you a decent power factor
> (without being too greedy).*

The best line capacitor to maximize power factor to a value of 1 is when you don't use a line capacitor. Any line capacitor will degrade the power factor of an SMPS. I'll quote what you linked: -

> **the minimum value is based on the actual conducted EMI and what levels
> are acceptable for your application.**

In other words, you choose the X capacitor based on keeping conducted emissions low but, you don't choose a value that is obscenely high because that will wreck your power factor: -

> **For example, a 0.47µF X capacitor across the line with 240VAC input at
> 60Hz (I know 50Hz would be more common, but lets make things worst
> case) will draw roughly 10W of apparent power at all times. If your
> SMPS is a 500W ATX power supply, then your power factor is 0.98.
> Great! If it is a 50W laptop power brick however, your power factor is
> now 0.8. Not so good.**

> *How Do I Choose a Value for an X-Capacitor?*

You choose it to significantly reduce your problems of conducted emissions as per [this earlier answer I gave you](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/542574/emi-input-filter-design) entitled EMI Input Filter Design. You have to address conducted emissions first and foremost and, live with the slightly degraded power factor that the X capacitor brings.

Again, a reminder from the answer you linked: -

> **It really just comes down to how noisy is your power supply, how much
> noise from the mains you want the supply to tolerate, and how good of
> a power factor you want. Power factor is almost always going to be
> lower priority though, since most countries require you to meet EMI
> standards above anything else.**